# Pandas - Expanding Z-Score Across Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate an expanding z-score for some time series data that I have in a DataFrame, but I want to standardize the data using the mean and standard deviation of multiple columns, rather than the mean and standard deviation within each column separately. I believe that I want to use some combination of groupby and DataFrame.expanding but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's some example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5),
                  columns=list('ABCDE'),
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-12-31', periods=5))

df.index.name = 'DATE'

df
```

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I have dates down the rows and the data series as individual columns. What I want is a new DataFrame of the same shape where I've calculated the expanding Z-Score. What I can't figure out how to do is to get the `df.expanding(2).mean()` method to aggregate across multiple columns. That is to say, rather than taking the expanding mean of column A and subtracting that from the value in column A, I want to take the expanding mean of the values in columns A through E and subtract that mean from the value in A.

If you think in terms of Excel, what I'm talking about is the difference between `=AVERAGE(B$2:B3)` and `=AVERAGE($B$2:$F3)`. To do the former is incredibly simple (`df.expanding(2).mean()`) but I can't figure out how to do the latter for the life of me.

I've experimented a lot with various combinations of `groupby`, `stack()`, and `expanding()` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own attempt at trying to calculate the expanding Z-Scores pooling all of the columns. Comments on how to do it more efficiently would be welcome.

```
def pooled_expanding_zscore(df, min_periods=2):
"""Calculates an expanding Z-Score down the rows of the DataFrame while pooling all of the columns.

Assumes that indexes are not hierarchical.
Assumes that df does not have columns named 'exp_mean' and 'exp_std'.
"""

# Get last sorted column name
colNames = df.columns.values
colNames.sort()
lastCol = colNames[-1]

# Index name
indexName = df.index.name

# Normalize DataFrame
df_stacked = pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=indexName).sort_values(by=[indexName,'variable'])

# Calculates the expanding mean and standard deviation on df_stacked
# Keeps just the rows where 'variable'==lastCol
df_exp = df_stacked.expanding(2)['value']
df_stacked.loc[:,'exp_mean'] = df_exp.mean()
df_stacked.loc[:,'exp_std'] = df_exp.std()

exp_stats = (df_stacked.loc[df_stacked.variable==lastCol,:]
            .reset_index()
            .drop(['index','variable','value'], axis=1)
            .set_index(indexName))

# add exp_mean and exp_std back to df
df = pd.concat([df,exp_stats],axis=1)

# Calculate Z-Score
df_mat = df.loc[:,colNames].as_matrix()
exp_mean_mat = df.loc[:,'exp_mean'].as_matrix()[:,np.newaxis]
exp_std_mat = df.loc[:,'exp_std'].as_matrix()[:,np.newaxis]
zScores = pd.DataFrame(
    (df_mat - exp_mean_mat) / exp_std_mat,
    index=df.index,
    columns=colNames)

# Use min_periods to kill off early rows
zScores.iloc[:min_periods-1,:] = np.nan

return zScores
```