# how to use pandas datetime index in expanding window

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm having trouble using a custom transformation with an expanding window. I have a function:

```
def minutes_since_previous(x):
    '''given datetime-indexed series x, 
    returns time difference in minutes between the last datetime 
    and the datetime of the previous nonnull value in each column.'''
    x = pd.Series(x)  # assumes aready sorted, else add .sort_index()
    tfinal=x.index[-1]
    allprev = x[:-1].dropna()  #all prev nonnulls. 
    if (len(allprev) > 0):
        tprev = allprev.index[-1]
        return (tfinal - tprev)
    else:
        return np.nan
```

and a series:

```
x
Out[116]:
datetime
2017-06-05 22:01:20.000    81.070099
2017-06-05 22:25:24.235          NaN
2017-06-05 22:33:13.000          NaN
2017-06-05 23:10:06.208          NaN
2017-06-05 23:11:40.437          NaN
2017-06-05 23:30:32.911          NaN
2017-06-06 06:19:41.934          NaN
2017-06-06 06:37:11.432          NaN
2017-06-06 06:41:37.000    93.681000
dtype: float32
```

The function works as expected on the series as a whole:

```
In [117]:
minutes_since_previous(x)
Out[117]:
Timedelta('0 days 08:40:17')
```

But when applied to the expanding window, I lose the datetime nature of the index, and instead of giving timedeltas since the first timestamp, I just get integer differences:

```
In [118]:
x.expanding().apply(minutes_since_previous)
Out[118]:
datetime
2017-06-05 22:01:20.000    NaN
2017-06-05 22:25:24.235    1.0
2017-06-05 22:33:13.000    2.0
2017-06-05 23:10:06.208    3.0
2017-06-05 23:11:40.437    4.0
2017-06-05 23:30:32.911    5.0
2017-06-06 06:19:41.934    6.0
2017-06-06 06:37:11.432    7.0
2017-06-06 06:41:37.000    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Perhaps .expanding() resets the index internally, but if so, how can I get what I'm looking for?

I searched "pandas expanding index" and found a question about [multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044764/pandas-expanding-z-score-across-multiple-columns), 
and many, many that were really about various kinds of resampling, but none dealing with losing index information.

Thanks ...

Comment: I can get what I want this way: `msp_x = pd.Series([minutes_since_previous(x[:i]) for i in range(1,len(x))], 
                name='msp_x') ` ... but it would be nice to use .expanding since that's what it's for :)

Comment: ... make that `...range(1, len(x)+1)...`